# How to properly apply WinJS.Binding.Template ListView GridLayout CSS?

Tags: css, windows-8, winjs

From this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f

I attempted to isolate Scenario 5 in to it's own project, but I get the following result:

original (correct): top.

isolated (incorrect): bottom.

[image]

It's obviously a CSS related issue, but I can't figure out what needs to change to cause the elements to display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simply a result of my javascript ignorance:

when using "strict", the key is the groupInfo in the binding of the list. to set it manually through javascript:

```
WinJS.UI.setOptions(listView5, {
        itemDataSource: myData4.dataSource,
        layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, groupInfo: groupInfo }
});
```